# Detect if an instance is running with kernel32::CreateMutexA

Tags: nsis

I'm working on an NSIS installer, and trying to check if a certain application is running before uninstalling. So, I use `kernel32::CreateMutexA` call. Here is the chunk:

```
System::Call 'kernel32::CreateMutexA(i 0, i 0, t "cmd.exe") i .r1 ?e'
Pop $R0
StrCmp $R0 0 +3
    MessageBox MB_USERICON "The application is already running."
Abort
```

I put it into `un.onInit`. Trouble is, the process (`cmd.exe` here) is never detected.

Did I miss something?

Tx.

Comment: Any number of instances of cmd.exe could be running on a system for multiple reasons

Comment: Actually, `cmd.exe` was just an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a simple solution; using [FindProcDLL plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/FindProcDLL_plug-in).

So:

```
FindProcDLL::FindProc "cmd.exe"
Pop $R0
StrCmp $R0 0 +3
 MessageBox MB_USERICON "The application is already running." IDOK
Abort
```

**P.S.** `FindProcDLL.dll` must be copied into `/Plugins`.

Comment: This does not work with NSIS 2.46, as is also documented on the page.

Answer (score 1):

All you are doing is creating a mutex with the global name `"cmd.exe"`. From the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682411%28VS.85%29.aspx) for `CreateMutex`:

> If lpName matches the name of an existing event, semaphore, waitable
>   timer, job, or file-mapping object, the function fails and the
>   GetLastError function returns ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE. This occurs
>   because these objects share the same name space.

So unless `cmd.exe` creates a handle to one of those types of objects with the name `"cmd.exe"`, this call will simply create a new mutex with that name and return you the (non-erronous) handle.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably using the wrong Win32 API function. Your CreateMutex tries to create a named mutex "something.exe". If there isn't one with that name it will succeed, so unless the process you're trying to check is creating a mutex with that name, you won't get the result you're after.

What you want is probably to enumerate all running processes and see if the one you're after is there. You can do this with ToolHelp32 from Win32 API - see [sample here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/processes.aspx). I don't know how easy it will be to convert it to 'pure' NSIS so you might want to write a DLL plugin, or check if there's an existing solution floating around the NSIS community.

Comment: Tx Idan.

It's strange. When I try with the installer itself (e.g. `my_setup.exe`), it works! But not with another process.

Comment: what works? from your code example the messagebox will appear if CreateMutexA has succeeded - that is, there isn't a named mutex with the name you provided.   
regardless of the behavior you're getting, it's the wrong solution to the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: `CreateMutexA()` succeeds with the installer itself. So, it's actually the right solution to detect if there is a running instance of the installer. But as you said, not the good one for any other process.

Comment: Yes, using a named mutex to allow a single instance of the installer is the right solution. It just wasn't clear that this was your intention in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of thing, I've used either the KillProcess or Find-Close-Terminate plugins for NSIS - see [here](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/FCT_plug-in)

Documentation is pretty straightforward, hopefully this does what you need - with a fairly minimal overhead.